# Is it possible to use Gmail properly via Outlook 2015 for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, ms-office, gmail, office-365

I'm a long-term GMail user. I tend to access my GMail via the GMail website or the Inbox app on my phone, but I find it convenient to be able to access GMail via Outlook 2015 for Mac, too. I have another email account that I access via Outlook, so it would be good to have everything in one place.

Every time I try to set GMail up on Outlook, it doesn't work correctly. I've followed many different tutorials, but something always fails to work: I end up with multiple drafts in my inbox when I login via gmail.com, for example, or deleting an email in Outlook doesn't cause the email to be archived on gmail.com.

Has anyone got Outlook 2015 (or any version of Outlook, for that matter) working properly with GMail? What settings should I use?

Comment: I've had similar issues with Outlook 2015 as far as calendars go (and potentially emails that never send, although appear that they do). I've never had issue with the Windows version accessing Gmail, so it seems to be a Mac software issue. Curious to see if there is a solution here.

Comment: I've had problems getting various mail clients on various platforms to work properly with GMail for years now. Not sure if there's some kind of reason (proprietary stuff that GMail does, maybe) why it never quite works!

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, I was just searching for a good mail app, and found that there is a new Gmail desktop app coming out in the next week. I'm going to try it, because I'm not quite satisfied with the other mail apps, and I like google's formatting. To manage multiple email accounts, you may consider having your other emails forwarded to your gmail account. That's what I've been doing. It's a temp fix for what you're looking for, but may help. I hope so.

Log in to your other email that you'd like to forward and follow similar instructions.

[image: Forwarding Instructions]